# WPF DataGrid Group

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Столкнулся с wpf впервые. Как сделать такую группировку?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
class StudentQuestions
{
    public StudentQuestions(string fio)
    {
        FIO = fio;
    }

    public string FIO { get; set; }
    public Questions QuestionsList { get; set; }
}

public class Questions : List<Question>
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Чтение вопросов из файлов структуры вида: "НомерВаринта, Вопрос"
    /// </summary>
    public void Read(string patchFile)
    {
            foreach (string question in File.ReadAllLines(patchFile, Encoding.UTF8))
            {
                string[] questionPars = question.Split(new char[] { ',', ' ' }, 2, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

                Add(new Question(questionPars[0], questionPars[1]));
            }
    }
}

public class Question
{
    public Question(string number, string description)
    {
        Number = number;
        Description = description;
    }

    public string Number { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Есть хороший [пример](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/dpatra/grouping-in-datagrid-in-wpf/).

Comment: Я находил его. Но не понимаю как его модифицировать под себя. Там идет просто коллекция объектов и их группировка. У меня же получается уже сгруппированая коллекция студентов которая имеет еще одну коллекцию - вопросы.